# Role value in JWT payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I am trying to setup a json web token based api authentication that will be used for various role based authorization in APIs.

Can I keep role value as a payload in Tokens ? Is is Safe ? If Not What is the what to save role like admin or user or merchant etc after successful login ?

Comment: Are you talking in theory or is there some actual code that you tried to write and need help with? For guides about JWT a simple google search will help you way more.

Comment: How have you tried to solve it so far?

Comment: You can keep it in payload. As long as you sign with decryption HMAC the whole message at  third part.

Comment: @cbll I think you did not understand my concern, I asked if pay load will be safe to keep the roles because if someones changes the role in payload by anyway they can access denied routes

Comment: @fingeron I have already coded the api logic,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can safely store whatever you like in a JWT, if you use the right type of token and name your custom field properly.

If the information is public and you just want to make sure the users can't change it to cheat, then simply use [JWS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515) and verify the token's signature. You can even do this client-side if the signature algorithm is based on a public key (RSA or ECDSA).

If the information to be stored on the token is not to be read by users, you can set up [JWE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516) (encrypted) tokens.

Your "role" field should be named [according to the spec, using a collision-resistant name](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.2) such as "com.yourdomainname.role" unless you are certain that your tokens will never be used by another client which also needs a "role" field with different semantics.